# Dataframe group with sort

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My script is currently combining multiple rows into one by using group by... however I'd also like to make sure that within each 'src' its sorted in ascending order by a field called 'numb'.

```
df = df.astype(str).groupby('src')['source_soe_dur'].agg('|'.join).to_frame('durMerge').reset_index()
```

I think I probably need to do something like: https://www.statology.org/pandas-groupby-sort/ but not sure how to adapt it to my use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting the entire dataframe before grouping is the same as sorting within each of the groups, so we can do the following:

```
df = df.astype(str).sort_values("numb", ascending=True).groupby('src')['source_soe_dur'].agg('|'.join).to_frame('durMerge').reset_index()
```